# Please help me in xpath html

Tags: python, html, xpath

I have html code:

```
<div class="text-conent" itemprop="articleBody" id="baiviet-container">
  <div class="baiviet-bailienquan pink-box-bg-light">
    <p><a href="...">title a</a></p>
  </div>
  <p><a href="...">title b</a></p>
  <p><a href="...">title c</a></p>
</div>
```

I used Xpath to get `a/@href` like:

```
.//div[id="baiviet-container"]/a/@href
```

I want get only:

```
<p><a href="...">title b</a></p>
<p><a href="...">title c</a></p>
```

and not get any `a/@href` in

```
<div class="baiviet-bailienquan pink-box-bg-light">...</div>
```

How can i do it?

Thanks you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath is almost work; it's only missing `p` in the step between `div` and `a`, and is also missing `@` for `id` attribute :

```
.//div[@id="baiviet-container"]/p/a/@href
```

quick test : http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/6b09187232acd7e5f6b7c3a617bd1e05

No need to worry about mistakenly getting `@href` from the inner `div`, because the XPath already uses child axes as mentioned in `div[@id="baiviet-container"]/p`. So it will consider a given `p` element, only if it is *direct child* of the `div` with `id` attribute equals `"baiviet-container"`.